# Why can't I start a bounty? (More than three bounties.)

Tags: support, asking-questions, bounty

Why can't I start a bounty in this question

[From the unit disk to the right half plane and $T(0)=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916099/from-the-unit-disk-to-the-right-half-plane-and-t0-3)

?

It's been more than 2 days since I asked. I wanted to put 100 points as bounty but there's no option to do that.

And I wonder why  not?

I am really interesting about knowing the solution of the exercise and as I didn't receive an understandable answer  I wanted to start a bounty, but again the 'start bounty' option does not appear.
 It's not fair..

[image]

Comment: I would suggest with respect to your linked question, that before placing a bounty on it, that you work to improve the question, and continue working on it, before spending more rep on a bounty.  If you can't solve it after a few days, and have improved the question during that time, then if you need/want to set a bounty on the improved question, you'll likely get better results (answers) that *also make sense* to you, if you improve/clarify first, and set a bounty afterwards.

Comment: I'm sympathetic with your desire to have a more detailed Answer, but it would not be desirable in my opinion to offer a bounty to get that.  The existing Answer gives a solution with no supporting argument or computation, but the Comments offered below the Answer suggest that author is capable of filling in those details.  Let's see if it doesn't get resolved that way.

Comment: @hardmath he finally edited the question, thank you :)

Comment: @amWhy thanks for your advice (: I'll keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 8):

You already have three currently running bounties. Three is the maximum number.

Once one of those bounties is awarded, you can place another one.

For reference see the final point in this standard reference:

[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: maximum number? , and why does that exists? does not make sense

Comment: I'd say it does make some sense. For example, if a user in a funny mood would start hundred bounties at the same time that would be a disruption, and annoying to those that happened to have a bounty active at the same time.

Comment: well in that case would make sense, but 3 or 4 I think it's totally fine.. Why would someone do that for fun, I think if you do that it's because you really need help

Comment: Yes I agree. The limit could also be 5 or it could be 2. That it is 3 is certainly a bit arbitrary.

Comment: @Isabella the limit is arbitrary, but it's also necessary to prevent abuse of transferring reputation to other accounts illegitimately, including rage-quitting.

Comment: @AndrewT. what is 'rage-quitting'?

Comment: @Isabella [Try this](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ragequit+definition)

Comment: @Isabella quitting a site (stop using it) while in rage, usually followed by questionable/annoying actions like vandalizing (e.g. deleting or blanking) own posts and sometimes zeroing their rep by putting big bounties on random posts...

Comment: @AndrewT. oh not my case definitely, I didn't want to lose my rep but it was necessary because no one answer them, and bounties might work as motivation.. or maybe not.